# My regular expression doesn't know when to stop

Tags: php, regex, greedy, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match this (the name in particular):

```
<tr>
    <th class="name">Name:</th>
    <td>John Smith</td>
</tr>
```

Like this:

```
preg_match('/<th class="name">Name:<\/th>.+?<td>(.+)<\/td>/s', $a, $b);
```

However, while it matches the name, it doesn't stop at the end of the name. It keeps going for another 150 or so characters. Why is this? I only want to match the name.

Comment: Use HTML parser please! Anyway, fix: `(.+)` --> `(.+?)`

Comment: replace `(.+)` to `([^<]+)`

Answer (score 3):

Make last quantifier non-greedy: `preg_match('/<th class="name">Name:<\/th>.+?<td>(.+?)<\/td>/s', $a, $b);`

Answer (score 0):

Dont use regex to parse HTML, Its very easy with DOMDocument:

```
<?php 
$html = <<<HTML
<tr>
    <th class="name">Name:</th>
    <td>John Smith</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="name">Somthing:</th>
    <td>Foobar</td>
</tr>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$ret = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr) {
    $ret[trim($tr->getElementsByTagName('th')->item(0)->nodeValue,':')] = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}

print_r($ret);
/*
Array
(
    [Name] => John Smith
    [Somthing] => Foobar
)
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/<th class="name">Name:<\/th>\s*<td>(.+?)<\/td>/s', $line, $matches);
```

Match only whitespace between the `</th>` and `<td>`, and non-greedy match for the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/<th class="name">Name:<\/th>.+?<td>(?P<name>.*)<\/td>/s', $str, $match);

echo $match['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your match

```
preg_match(!<tr>\s*<th[^>]*>Name:</th>\s*<td>([^<]*)</td>\s*</tr>!s)
```

it will work perfectly.